# java-gearman-client - Producing more and more threads

Tags: java, multithreading, gearman

I have written an application that submits jobs (client) to one or more workers using [Gearman](http://www.gearman.org), especially [java-gearman-service](http://code.google.com/p/java-gearman-service/) 0.6.2.

Now i'm running an infinite loop to check every 10 Seconds if i need to submit a new Job to the Jobserver. There's some logic behind that. Note that i just want to submit them, not get a result or callback.

Basically what i do is:

```
Gearman gearman = Gearman.createGearman();
GearmanClient client = gearman.createGearmanClient();
client.addServer(gearman.createGearmanServer("someip",somePort);
while(true) {
    // get the jobs to submit from the application logic
    client.submitBackgroundJob("functionname","dataBytes");
    // sleep for a few seconds.
}
```

This produces more and more threads until so much memory is consumed that an `OutOfMemory` Exception will be thrown.

I tried to instanciate `Gearman` and `GearmanClient` in the loop - and shut them down with:

```
client.shutdown();
gearman.shutdown();
```

after all Jobs were submitted, but this results in:

> 28 [gearman-1] INFO gearman - [127.0.1.1:4730] : Connected
>
> ```
>  634 [main] FATAL main - Exception!
> ```
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at org.gearman.impl.util.GearmanUtils.toString(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.serverpool.AbstractConnectionController.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.server.remote.GearmanServerRemote$InnerGearmanConnectionHandler.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.core.GearmanConnectionManager$SocketHandlerImpl.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.reactor.SocketImpl.closeConnection(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.reactor.SocketImpl.close(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.core.GearmanConnectionManager$SocketHandlerImpl$Connection.close(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.server.remote.GearmanServerRemote.shutdown(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.GearmanImpl.shutdown(Unknown Source)
>
> at MyApplication.start(ClientManager.java:clientShutdownLine)
>
> 31 [gearman-1] INFO gearman - [127.0.1.1:4730] : Disconnected
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>
> at org.gearman.impl.client.GearmanJobReturnImpl.eof(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.client.ClientImpl.failTo(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.client.ClientImpl.onClose(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.client.ClientImpl.access$700(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.client.ClientImpl$InnerConnectionController.onClose(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.serverpool.AbstractConnectionController.closeServer(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.serverpool.AbstractConnectionController.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.server.remote.GearmanServerRemote$InnerGearmanConnectionHandler.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.core.GearmanConnectionManager$SocketHandlerImpl.onAccept(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.reactor.NioReactor$1.completed(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.gearman.impl.reactor.NioReactor$1.completed(Unknown Source)
>
> at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Unknown Source)
>
> at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Unknown Source)
>
> at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

How can i avoid Gearman-Java-Service producing so much threads after time?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version. I think you may be seeing these issues:

- http://code.google.com/p/java-gearman-service/issues/detail?id=32&can=1
- http://code.google.com/p/java-gearman-service/issues/detail?id=33&can=1

Also note that the [submitBackgroundJob](http://java-gearman-service.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/org/gearman/GearmanClient.html#submitBackgroundJob%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29) is an asynchronous call, and some queuing is is occurring in the background. If you are submitting jobs faster than the client can dish them out, an out of memory exception will happen. Given it looks like you are waiting for a few seconds, that might not be the case, but try this:

```
Gearman gearman = Gearman.createGearman();
GearmanClient client = gearman.createGearmanClient();
client.addServer(gearman.createGearmanServer("someip",somePort);
while(true) {
    // get the jobs to submit from the application logic
    GearmanJobReturn jobReturn = client.submitBackgroundJob("functionname","dataBytes");
    while(!jobReturn.isEOF()) {jobReturn.poll();}
}
```

The [GearmanJobReturn](http://java-gearman-service.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/org/gearman/GearmanJobReturn.html) will poll the job handle (or an error message) on background jobs before reaching the end-of-file. This will also allow the job to be fully submitted before you submit the next job.

Don't shutdown the service between submissions. That slows down everything. Any connections already established are closed and you need to re-establish the connection to submit the next job.